# exclude weekends from month except a particular weekend

Tags: sql-server

I have written the following query in SQL Server

**(QUERY)**

```
select ISNULL(count(WORKHOUR) ,'-') AS present, 
ISNULL((count(*)-count(WORKHOUR)),'-') AS absent,
ISNULL(cast(SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), WORKHOUR))/60 as nvarchar(3)) + ':' + cast(SUM(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), WORKHOUR))%60 as nvarchar(2)),'-') AS TOTALWRKHRS,
ISNULL(cast(AVG(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), WORKHOUR))/60 as nvarchar(3)) + ':' + cast(AVG(DateDiff(MINUTE,  CAST('0:00' as time), WORKHOUR))%60 as nvarchar(2)),'-') AS AVGWRKHRS
from "+**currMonthVal**+" m,"+**currYearVal**+" e WHERE E.EMPID=M.EMPID AND E.LOCATION=M.LOCATION AND M.EMPID = ?
and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, attdate) not IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),ATTDATE,3) not in ("+**resultantHL**+")
```

where currMonthVal and currYearVal are Month and Year values passed from outside and resultantHL are the holiday_dates (like '24/12/2016','25/12/2016') passed from outside.

This query works fine.

I have a table named **WORKING_DAYS** as follows:'

```
COLUMN_ID     COLUMN_NAME     DATA_TYPE
---------------------------------------
1                ID           NUMBER
2               WDATE         DATE
3             INSTITUTE_ID    NUMBER
```

and sample data in table is:

```
COLUMN_ID     WDATE     INSTITUTE_ID
---------------------------------------
1            05-12-15     1
2            19-11-16     1
```

These two dates in table are actually declared as extra working days in respective months and fall on either Saturday or Sunday.

My requirement is :
I have excluded all Saturday and Sunday from the month in the query above [using DATENAME(WEEKDAY, attdate) not IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')] but I do not want to exclude the above two dates in WORKING_DAYS table but include them
And I want to do that in the same query if possible as that too in WHERE clause.

How can I do so?

***Note:***  I have already retrieved the extra working days from WORKING_DAYS table and stored in a string variable and wish to pass that variable value in the condition

Answer (score 0):

An OR your date is also on WORKING_DAYS should suffice :

Replace

```
DATENAME(WEEKDAY, attdate) not IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
```

by

```
(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, attdate) not IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') or adddate in (select wdate from WORKING_DAYS))
```

Comment: I'm glad to be of help. :-)